# Make page flip animation on iPhone (like magazine)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation

What would be the best approach to make one page flip like a real magazine? Like I put the finger in the corner of the screen then flip the page, as in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dy4Y9j7COgg&feature=related).

Is it a sequence of images? All images are in one View or Imageview? Or there is another way to do it using the some stuff of the SDK? Does this effect exist, or would I have to write it?

Comment: This is definitely not from the SDK. Let's wait if there are some third parties libraries that do the same thing ;)

Answer (score 2):

This would fix your magazine problem... https://github.com/ole/leaves/tree/twopages

Answer (score 1):

If it was me i'd try to use the API that someone has provided, save yourself some trouble:

[CodeFlakes PaperTouch API](http://www.code-flakes.com/)

Comment: That would be nice but will cost some $$$... Is there nothing allready made in the SDK nativle for this? this is so simple and so obvious that a lot of people would be doing for iPhone and Apple did not make anything ?

Comment: do you know of any provider who offers the same for Android by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

That's just a sequence of images as the backgrounds, and the "text" scales horizontally narrower.

For detail implementation you need to ask the original developer.

Answer (score 1):

[UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPageViewController) is a new class in iOS 5 that you might be interested in if you don't have to support older iOS versions.

*(before someone warns me about NDA, note that this class was announced publicly on one of wwdc keynote slides, I'm just giving a link to docs which can only be accessed by iOS Developer Program members)*